# Using a Generic Class as Upper Bound of a Type Parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm struggling with generic bounds for type parameters in Java. What I want to achieve is the following:

- I have a generic class (`Generic<>` (1) in the sample code)
- I have a generic class where the type parameter should scope over types of the first generic class (`UsingGeneric<>` (2); this is already strange, as it forces me to repeat the `Comparable` constraint)
- I then want to instantiate this second class with a third class (`MyGeneric` (3)) which extends a concrete application of the first class.

Think of it like this: You have a generic container class where the elements are constrained. You have a generic iterator class that scopes over such containers. Now you want to create a concrete iterator for a concrete container.

The problem: Statement (4) won't compile, complaining:
`Type parameter MyGeneric is not within its bound; should extend Generic<MyGeneric>.`

The problem seems to be that Java forces me to repeat the type variable in the upper bound - which is kind of nonsensical as, to stay with the container example, I don't want my concrete container to be of a type of "container of container". I still want it to be of type "container of comparable". I.e the `UsingGeneric` class should have a signature where *the primary type variable is decoupled from the type variable of the upper bound*, somewhat like `UsingGeneric<T extends Generic<S> & Comparable<S>>`. Which is not possible, AFAIK.

What am I doing wrong?

Sample code:

```
class Test {

  static class Generic<E extends Comparable<E>> {}  // (1)

  static class UsingGeneric<T extends Generic<T> & Comparable<T>> {} // (2)

  static class MyGeneric extends Generic<Integer> {}  // (3)

  static UsingGeneric<MyGeneric> myUsingGeneric;  // (4) - won't compile

}
```

Comment: Well, one problem is that `MyGeneric extends Generic<Integer>` defines the generic type to be `Integer` but `UsingGeneric<T extends Generic<T> & Comparable<T>` requires it to _also_ extend or implement `Generic<T>` which `Integer` clearly won't do.

Comment: You would need something like: `UsingGeneric<T extends Generic<E>, E extends Comparable<E>>`

Comment: @Slaw This looks great. It just forces me to have a second type parameter, `UsingGeneric<MyGeneric,Integer> myUsingGeneric`, which would be kind of redundant but compiles. Consider making an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your current code doesn't compile is because:

```java
class UsingGeneric<T extends Generic<T> & Comparable<T>> { ... }
```

Requires that the type argument used must implement *both* `Generic<T>` and `Comparable<T>`. The `Integer` class may implement the latter but does not implement the former, thus the compilation error. And the reason you have to specify the `Comparable` bounds again is because `UsingGeneric` has declared a *new* type parameter, `T`, which is being used as the *type argument* to the `Generic` bound, which is a parameterized type in this context. Since the type parameter of `Generic` is bounded by `Comparable` you must ensure the type parameter of `UsingGeneric` has compatible bounds.

That said, what you seem to be looking for is a way to specify the `Comparable` type used *with* the `Generic` type, while not requiring that the type implements both interfaces. This will require two type parameters:

```java
class UsingGeneric<T extends Generic<E>, E extends Comparable<E>> { ... }
```

This may seem redundant at first but all the information is necessary. Now we have `E` being used as the *type argument* of the `Generic` bound of `T` while allowing `E` to be a different type than `T`. But again, since the type parameter of `Generic` is bounded by `Comparable` we have to make sure `E` has compatible bounds.